# build & install GTK library

Tags: gtk, embedded-linux

I need to build & install GTK library so i need source code for it. So i searched & come to this link which contains its GIT hub path.
http://www.gtk.org/download/

Is this procedure correct ?

```
git clone git://git.gnome.org/gtk+
cd gtk+
./configure
make
make install
```

1> As per link it states it requires some libraries. Do i need to perform the same step for --->  `glib, pango, gdk-pixbuf and atk`.
2> Does `cairo` comes with `pango` or have to be downloaded, build & install seprately ?
3> Does i need `xlib` ?

Please suggest `what all dependency packages are required by GTK ?` which i have to compile & install seprately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post should give you a full idea of what you need to build GTK+

http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-building.html

Comment: Thanks  most of the things i got but as per link-->> Several environment variables are useful to pass to set before running configure.   --->>> is it necessary to export -->> CPPFLAGS, LDFLAGS, PKG_CONFIG_PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, PATH ... ?

Comment: i think this is needed if and only if i change the install path like this ---> --prefix=/opt/gtk     ----> if i use simple  ./congifure  then no need to export these . right ?

Comment: also to download i need following extension .git  ---------------  git clone git://git.gnome.org/gtk+.git

Comment: its always safer to set the paths (environment variables) to insure that everything is linked correctly... these are only 4 simple variables so I don't see how it'll complicate things for you

Comment: use the git client to download the library if thats what you mean by extension .git

Comment: you can download from [here](http://git-scm.com/)

Comment: and please next time do your research before asking trivial questions like these

Comment: http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/INSTALL.html    -->> --prefix=PATH will change the default /usr/local installation path  ---> if we do not put prefix then no need to export new environmental variables